# how to add start button in telegram bot with python-telegran-bot sdk?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to write a simple bot for telegram with [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) SDK. I want to show a "START" keyboard button instead of typing "/start" command to work with my bot. How to do this with python-telegram-bot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know when you start using a bot for the first time telegram shows that **start button** itself but after the first message is sent you won't see that keyboard button anymore all you need to do is clearing the bot's history to see that again.

On the other hand if you want to have a keyboard button that can be shown anytime you want, all you should do is implementing a custom keyboard. You can find useful information about keyboards [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards).